# Setting a minimum content size on a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a view at the top of a view controller, and a tableview underneath it.

I've made it such that as the tableview is scrolled up the top view scrolls up too, up to a maximum amount, of lets say 50 points.

The tableview also has a top inset of 50:

```
tableView = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

... so that it's cells start below the top view.

And in the scrollview delegate there is some code along the lines of:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let scrollViewYOffset = ...
    topViewHeightConstraint.constant = max(minTopViewHeight, minTopViewHeight - scrollViewYOffset)
}
```

This ensures as the user drags down on the tableview the top view 'sticks' to it, and is also pushed up when the user pushes the table view up.

I've drawn this picture to better describe what the Storyboard looks like:

[image]

So far so good. When there are a lot of cells and the user scrolls the table view up, the top view remains at it's minimum height nicely.

**But** if you are scrolled up - so the top view is at it's minimum - then the number of cells are reduced, the top view pings back down to it's maximum height.

This is because the actual content size of the tableview has dropped below its bounds height, and so as a scrollview it brings the top of the content to the top of the scrollview again (plus the 50 point top inset of course).

---

I would like to be able to scroll the tableview up, so the top view remains at its minimum height, regardless of the number of cells it contains - i.e. regardless of it's content size.

Can anyone think of a clever way to set a minimum content size on the table view?

*(So far I've tried messing around with the footer, having a cell at the bottom that is essentially a spacer - this messes up the tableview's logic and some reordering code I have in there. I've attempted to coerce the offers etc. to my will, but haven't quite worked out how to achieve this.)*

I would greatly appreciate some UI genius to point me in the right direction :) Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Thank you for all the answers and comments.

After trying various types of footer and header views, tweaking constraints & layout priorities on scroll, adding spacer cells, putting the tableview inside a scrollview, etc. - it finally occurred to me I was making this more complicated than I needed to, and should just update the cause of the problem on the scrollViewDidScroll, the `contentInset` value.

See the answer below for a code example that achieves the behaviour I was looking for.

Comment: Have you tried with setting empty tableView.tableViewFooter and playing with its frame (height), or you just tried a fake cell? TableViewFooter would not affect your cells logic.

Comment: I am not sure why you are needing to set a minimum content size.  If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you should create the top view on your view controller and then add a tableview below the top view and pin the top of the tableview to the bottom of the top view.  Create an outlet for the height constraint of the top view.  As you scroll, use the scrollview delegate methods to shorten the height of the top view until it reaches the minimum height.  Because the tableview is pinned to the bottom of the top view it will move up as the too view gets smaller.

Comment: @PredragSamardzic Yes I tried a footer. The issue is it's sticky to the bottom, so appears over the cells. The fake cell option was better, but it doesn't work well with some reordering UI I have in there.

Comment: @SteveTrombley That's pretty much what I've done :) But when the content of the table view is smaller than its height, it pings it back to the content inset.

Comment: @Jon Cox I do not mean section footer, but tableFooter. tableView.tableViewFooter - that one is not sticky. Also if you want section headers/footers not to be sticky change tableView style to grouped instead of plain (and if you want to eliminate default section headers/footers from grouped tableView, just set their height to 0.01 or CGFloat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `contentInset` is what is causing the tableview to ping back to the wrong point, I simply needed to adjust the content inset as the tableview was scrolled up/down.

Here is some example code of what I did:

```
let maxPointsTopViewCanMoveUp: CGFloat = 50

let topInset = abs(min(max(-maxPointsTopViewCanMoveUp, scrollView.contentOffset.y), 0))
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

let amountToMoveTopViewUp = maxPointsTopViewCanMoveUp - topInset
topViewToSuperviewTopConstraint.constant = amountToMoveTopViewUp
```

This is called from the `scrollViewDidScroll` of the tableview.

It means that when there are too few cells in the tableview to fill the content, the top the tableview sticks in the place it had been scrolled up to (i.e. the amount it had pushed up the top view).

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas that you can try:

- Create a "dummy" row on index 0 and make it's height be 50 (it will be hidden below the top view).  Maybe you can leave that dummy row in section 0 and the rest of your data in section 1, so you don't have to think about it when deleting your data.
- Or, instead of a dummy row, you can set the height of the tableView's header to be 50
- Maybe set a minimum height constraint on the tableView, and keep it's content compression resistance priority high.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Diogo. The dummy row is a nice idea, but it unfortunately messes up some reordering UI I have.

Comment: I'll try the others again though this evening and report back.

Comment: I hope it goes well! If you want a fixed content for that hidden area, I think the tableView header will be the best option.